# DecimalFormat(), probleme with russian computers

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I have a `BigDecima`l which I convert to a `String` to do some modifications on it.
At the end I try to convert it back to `BigDecimal` using this part of the code:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
Amt = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(amount);
```

At the end I expect my `BigDecimal` to be like this for example `"135.40"`
and it works, but on a Russian computer I get `"135.00"`. I don't understand why, is this kind of a bug or something?

Comment: im confused. define what you mean "Russian" computer

Comment: when my code is executed on a Russian computer or when it uses the "Russian" as a language

Comment: either shouldnt make a difference. there is something else that is different and produces this anomaly. it is not about what computer you use but more like which java version you use

Comment: It's about the Locale

Comment: My guess would be russian locale uses `comma` as decimal separator. I'm not sure how `DecimalFormat` handles it, but check what string gets passed into it. It either gets passed `"135.40"` and expects a `comma` due to being locale-aware or gets passed `"135,40"` as an output of some other locale-aware procedure, but looks for `period`. Check `decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols()` or `.toPattern()` idk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decimal separator in Russian locale is `,`. That is why the number is truncated at `.` which is invalid for Russian locale.

`decimalFormat.parse("135,40")` should give you the desired bigdecimal.

If you want to parse the numbers with `.`, change the locale of `DecimalFormat`:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)formatter;
```

Comment: it wokrs, i used the code you provided before i parse my BigDecimal and it works. thank you